# Big-O of Upperbound on the Regret of Exp3

Tags: online-algorithms, multiarmed-bandit

I'm having difficulty understanding how to compute Big-O for the upper bound on the regret in Exp3 algorithm.
I think the actual algorithm isn't quite important for my question but since I couldn't find the relevant material to work out so let me shorten the detailed notations.

So, the following is the famous bound on the regret of Exp3.

### Theorem(Expected regret of Exp3)

The expected regret of Exp3 with learning rate $\eta > 0$ is;
$$
\mathcal{R}_T \leq \frac{\ln N}{\eta} + T \eta
$$

And most of the materials(mostly lecture notes: [here](https://haipeng-luo.net/courses/CSCI659/2022_fall/lectures/lecture1.pdf) or [here](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Ewmkoolen/MLT_2021/slides9.pdf)) that I went through are concluding the derivation of the above theorem by saying that if you set $\eta$ to be as follows, you get the following Big-O version of the upperbound. But how do we compute it?

### Collorary

The expected regret of Exp3 with learning rate $\eta = \sqrt{\frac{ \ln N}{T}}$ is;
$$
\mathcal{R}_T \leq O(\sqrt{T \ln N})
$$

Comment: oh, shoot,,, it's just differentiating the RHS of the theorem w.r.t $\eta$ and solving it for 0 as usual, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper bound has the form $\frac{A}x+Bx$. This is in both terms and also in the sum a convex function over the positive half-axis, raising to infinity for $x\to 0$ and $x\to\infty$. So there is a unique minimum.

This minimum can be determined via calculus or via mean inequalities,
$$
\frac{\frac{A}x+Bx}2\ge\sqrt{AB},
$$
with equality for $\frac{A}x=Bx\implies x=\sqrt{\frac{A}{B}}$.